# The sum of the numbers on the paper

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

$A$ is a set with six members that the sum of its members are $40$. Consider all the subsets of $A$(that do not have duplicated members.).We write the sum of them on a paper.Which number did we write on the paper?

> $a.1100$
>
> $b.1280$
>
> $c.2560$
>
> $d.3100$

Comment: You really have to start adding some personal input to your questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: It doesn't actually *matter* what the entries are so long as they are all distinct.  They could be irrational, positive, negative, zero, complex, whatever...

Let the set be $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6\}$ with each term distinct.

We are told that $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=40$

If we try to add all subsets together, organized by which subset they come from, it will be messy:

$$(x_1)+(x_2)+\dots+(x_1+x_2)+(x_1+x_3)+\dots+(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_6)$$

Let us *instead* approach in the following way:

In how many subsets will $x_1$ be in?  How many times then does $x_1$ appear in the sum above?  How about $x_2$?  $x_3$? ...

This implies that...

> The sum of the entries in all subsets is equal to $32x_1+32x_2+32x_3+32x_4+32x_5+32x_6$

but since $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_6=40$ this simplifies to be...